# Download MariaDB Column Store on Windows 10

Tags: database, mariadb, columnstore

I have been searching for a while that how to install mariadb column store on windows. I have Windows 10 on my system. How can I install Column Store on Windows?

Answer (score 1):

There is no ColumnStore download package for Windows operating systems.

From the [MariaDB Foundation website](https://mariadb.org/columnstore-native/):

"MariaDB ColumnStore does not currently support all the same operating systems as MariaDB Server (currently no Windows, no Mac OS X). Dependent on the flavour of Linux you use, download and installation will be different."

Workarounds:

- [Hyper-V virtualization](https://mariadb.com/de/resources/blog/testing-mariadb-columnstore-on-windows-using-hyper-v/)
- [Vagrant + Docker](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/columnstore-getting-started-mariadb-columnstore-docker-vagrant-and-windows-/)